# Intra Application communication (Silverlight to Java)

Tags: java, silverlight

I have a java desktop app and I have a silverlight client app running on a computer.  What are my best options for communicating between the two of them?  Can the silverlight client app host a wcf so the desktop app can talk directly to it while bypassing the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java and Silverlight both support TCP Sockets, so use them. [Sockets in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248%28VS.95%29.aspx) And [Java Sockets](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/) are good places to start.

You might also need [Google Protocol Buffers + Java](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html) and [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for compatible serialization.  Good luck!